# configurar tomEE con Docker

Tags: java, java-ee, docker, tomee

muchas gracias por su tiempo, estoy aprendiendo `Docker`  y  `tomEE` y me gustaría poder configurarlo llevo mas de un día tratando con todo lo que encontré en la web pero aun no consigo siquiera entrar en el `manager` les dejo mi archivo `yml` de `docker`

```
version: '3'
services:
   tomcat:
      image: tomee
      ports: 
         - "8888:8080"
      volumes:
         - ./codigo_fuente/:/usr/local/tomee/webapps/
      expose: 
         - "8080"
      command: ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

también cambie el `xml` para el usuario y contraseña

```
     <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="123as" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

y el `context` ubicado en el  `webapps/manager/META-INF`

```
    <Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.0\.0\.1:8888" />
</Context>
```

y aun con esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
espero puedan ayudarme saludos y de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: No creo que esté relacionado, pero ... ¿Por qué las barras inversas en la IP `127\.0\.0\.1`?

Comment: asi estaba en la documentacion

Comment: por las dudas ya las quite y nada

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, intenta modificar un tanto el xml de usuarios y roles por esto

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<role rolename="manager-script" />
<role rolename="manager-jmx" />
<role rolename="manager-status" />
<role rolename="admin-gui" />
<role rolename="admin-script"/>

<user username="admin" password="123as" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script,admin" />
```